# Why do Pymongo returns E11000 duplicate error when using python console

Tags: python, mongodb, pycharm, pymongo

I am following the tutorial in [Pymongo documentation](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#prerequisites)

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
import datetime

client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
test_db = client.test_db #This creates a database
posts = test_db.posts #This creates a collection of documents

post = {"author": "Doug",
        "text": "My first blog post!",
        "tags": ["mongodb", "python"],
        "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
```

The code works in both cases: press run in IDE or run line by line in python console. However, whenever I run it in python console, it gives me the

```
pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: text_database.another_collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f505d1e233d210283dd4632') }, full error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'keyPattern': {'_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'_id': ObjectId('5f505d1e233d210283dd4632')}, 'errmsg': "E11000 duplicate key error collection: text_database.another_collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId('5f505d1e233d210283dd4632') }"}
```

error. It is normal in creating a new empty collection and inserting the document except the duplicate error. May I ask why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `insert_one()` your `post` dictionary will look like this

```
>>>print(post)
{'_id': ObjectId('5f506285b54093f4b9202abe'),
 'author': 'Doug',
 'date': datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 3, 3, 27, 1, 729287),
 'tags': ['mongodb', 'python'],
 'text': 'My first blog post!'}
```

Now you trying to insert again with same `post` it will throw an error because now it has an `_id` field.

If you don't want to update the dictionary after insert. You can insert using the copy of dictionary. you can create copy of dictionary using `dict(post)` or `post.copy()`

Now you can change your insert as below

```
post_id = posts.insert_one(dict(post)).inserted_id
```

or

```
post_id = posts.insert_one(post.copy()).inserted_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I didn't insert the post again. In fact, insert_one doesn't cause the error but the inserted_id causes the duplicate error.

Comment: `inserted_id` doesn't cause error because it is a result after successful insertion. `insert_one()` returns [InsertOneResult](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertOneResult) on success